# how can I stream in grayscale? (Android)

Tags: android, colors, accessibility, render, inversion-of-control

when I stream from my android smartphone it doesnt capture any color manipulations like grayscale. Because the color inversion is applied too late in the rendering pipeline to be included in a screenshot or video recording.

if there is no app out there I will try to code it myself. Any advice how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and ask on [meta] if you have any questions :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.